# Infragistics WebTab AutoReLoading all tabs

Tags: asp.net, .net, tabs, infragistics

I have a WebTab with more than 10 tabs(ContentTabItem) which has the following properties:

```html
<ig:WebTab ID="WebTab1" 
    runat="server" 
    Width="100%" 
    Height="2000px" 
    DisplayMode="MultiRow" 
    TabOrientation="Horizontal" 
    SelectedTab="8" 
    ThreeDEffect="False" 
    DynamicTabs="false">
    <Tabs>
    ...
    </Tabs>
    <PostBackOptions EnableLoadOnDemandUrl="true" 
                     EnableReloadingOnTabClick="true"/>
</ig:WebTab>
```

The tabs contains **DetailsViews** and **GridViews** which bind with database.
When i change something on a tab I have to double click the other tabs in order to refresh and bind again with the DB.

I need to modify the code so **ALL** the tabs will **AUTO** refresh when a change occured.

With the old version of Infragistics all the tabs refreshes automatically.

```html
<igtab:UltraWebTab ID="UltraWebTab1" 
    runat="server" 
    Height="2000px" 
    Width="750px" 
    DisplayMode="MultiRow" 
    SelectedTab="8" 
    ThreeDEffect="False" 
    DynamicTabs="false" >
    <Tabs>
    ...
    </Tabs>
    <RoundedImage FillStyle="LeftMergedWithCenter" />
    <BorderDetails ColorLeft="White" ColorTop="White" />
    <DefaultTabStyle BackColor="Silver">
    </DefaultTabStyle>
    </igtab:UltraWebTab>
```

I have tried to enable the following **PostBackOptions** parameters with no results.

> EnableAjax="true"
>   EnableDynamicUpdatePanels="true"
>   EnableAsyncUpdateAllTabs="true"
>   EnableReloadingUnselectedTab="true"

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

A not very good solution is to use some **javascript**.

On WebTab tag I added the following *ClientEvents-SelectedIndexChanged="SelectedIndexChanged"*.

where the ***SelectedIndexChanged*** function is

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e) {
        var tabs = $find("<%= UltraWebTab1.ClientID %>");
        var current = tabs.get_selectedIndex();
        tabs.set_selectedIndex(current, true);
    }
</script>
```

So when I change the tab, the selected tab reloads and binds with the correct data.